get the azure web app instance ids using Java sdk
I need to get all the instance ids of azure web app deployed in java.
I am testing using WebAppInstanceStatusCollection class but not getting proper method to list down instances.
Edit :
I tried different method but its giving me wrong instance id
    AppServiceManager appservice= AppServiceManager.authenticate(credential,profile);
WebAppsClient appservicec = appservice.serviceClient().getWebApps();
   
PagedIterable<WebSiteInstanceStatusInner> webAppid = appservicec.listInstanceIdentifiers("rg","app");
            return webAppid;


Show the code you tried.

Hi @Rohi_Dev_1.0 Could you include Azure Portal image to better understand what exactly you want?

I need to get instance id if you have scale out instances to 1+

Alternatively, you can make use of below REST API call to list Azure Web App instance IDs:
GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/{name}/instances?api-version=2024-04-01

I have one Azure Web App with 3 scale-out instances in it as below:

To fetch these scale-out instance IDs, you can make use of below sample java code:
package org.example;  
  
import com.azure.identity.AzureCliCredential;  
import com.azure.identity.AzureCliCredentialBuilder;  
import com.azure.core.credential.TokenRequestContext;  
import com.azure.core.credential.AccessToken;  
  
import java.net.URI;  
import java.net.http.HttpClient;  
import java.net.http.HttpRequest;  
import java.net.http.HttpResponse;  
import java.io.IOException;  
import org.json.JSONArray;  
import org.json.JSONObject;  
  
public class Main {  
    public static void main(String[] args) {  
        String subscriptionId = "subId";  
        String resourceGroup = "rgname";  
        String appServiceName = "demowebapp110";  
        String apiVersion = "2022-03-01";  
        String url = "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/" + subscriptionId  
                + "/resourceGroups/" + resourceGroup + "/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/"  
  + appServiceName + "/instances?api-version=" + apiVersion;  
  
        AzureCliCredential credential = new AzureCliCredentialBuilder().build();  
        TokenRequestContext requestContext = new TokenRequestContext()  
                .addScopes("https://management.azure.com/.default");  
  
        try {  
            AccessToken token = credential.getToken(requestContext).block();  
            String bearerToken = token.getToken();  
  
            HttpClient client = HttpClient.newHttpClient();  
  
            HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()  
                    .uri(URI.create(url))  
                    .header("Authorization", "Bearer " + bearerToken)  
                    .GET()  
                    .build();  
  
            HttpResponse<String> response = client.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());  
  
            System.out.println("Response status: " + response.statusCode());  
  
            if (response.statusCode() == 200) {  
                String responseBody = response.body();  
                JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(responseBody);  
                JSONArray instances = jsonResponse.getJSONArray("value");  
  
                System.out.println("\nInstance Information:");  
                System.out.println("=====================");  
                for (int i = 0; i < instances.length(); i++) {  
                    JSONObject instance = instances.getJSONObject(i);  
                    String id = instance.getString("id");  
                    String name = instance.getString("name");  
  
                    System.out.println("Instance " + (i + 1) + ":");  
                    System.out.println("  ID   : " + id);  
                    System.out.println("  Name : " + name);  
                    System.out.println("---------------------");  
                }  
            } else {  
                System.out.println("Error: Received non-OK response. Status code: " + response.statusCode());  
            }  
  
        } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {  
            e.printStackTrace();  
        }  
    }  
}

Output:

Reference:
Web Apps - List Instance Identifiers - REST API (Azure App Service) | Microsoft

How it will access the token and gets authenticate?

In my code, I logged in to Terminal with az login command and used AzureCliCredential method to get access token.

I followed the above approached which I mentioned and it did worked well. I was missing while adding instances. Thank you for the help
